# Как в dbus включить лог?

Tags: linux

`dbus-monitor` - это вызов на консоль.

А как положить всю историю в /var/log/ ?

И как её посмотреть, что там было 5, 10, 15 минут назад?

Comment: Ну если достаточно в произвольный файл, то проще всего просто перенаправить вывод в этот файл `dbus-monitor >>/var/log/dbusmon.log &` амперсанд в конце строки говорит отправить задачу в фоновое выполнение, что бы консоль не занимала. Как посмотреть - видимо открыть файл потом и посмотреть что в нем

Comment: Это понятно. Первая строчка в моём вопросе. А как настроить это навсегда? В какой конфиг и что забить, что бы оно само ложило лог? Или оно не умеет?

Comment: что значит не умеет. так как я написал оно же пишет нормально ? если пишет  - значит умеет. А загрузка системы - это не конфиги а обычные выполняемые скрипты все что там написано тупо выполняется. И если в скрипты загрузки дописать такую строку то она конечно сработает. правда во всех дистрибутивах linux скрипты загрузки немного по разному устроены. например, каталог /etc/local.d есть или файл /etc/rc.local ?

Comment: Да, но делать свой rc.local на debian-like системе, где уже по-умолчанию всё обёрнуто в свои init.d скрипты, это малость сказать - моветон.

Comment: У меня тут есть один дебиан, на нем из коробки лежит пустой rc.local, вот для таких случаев его и положили. Хотите красиво, возьмите любой скрипт из rc.d и сделайте обертку. Мне как то не нравилось, что система на 386 камне грузится больше 2х минут. Переписал загрузку тупо нужными строками в одном файле, на slakware манер - 6 секунд стала грузится. В оптимизации ничего плохого невижу

Comment: Хорошо, с этим вопрос решили. Будет самопальная обёртка в rc.local. А как листать историю назад? Вот у меня рухнули 3 браузера разом, и два из них ругнулись при этом на dbus. Как мне посмотреть что там было на шине в этот момент? Как пролистать историю назад? Или это глупый вопрос - раз по умолчанию нет log файла?

Comment: Локальные консоли по Shft+PgUp листаются, но там буфер страницы на 2, не больше. Если удаленно, то у каждого средства которым можно подключатся свои предпочтения, putty то-же экрана 2 листает. Без лога больше ни как. Еще для варианта с консолью есть `tee`. `dbus-monitor | tee имя-файла` и на консоли останется и в лог запишется

Comment: И в rc.local обертка не нужна. Стандартная загрузка готовыми загрузочными скриптами с обертками - это rc.d, а нестандартная свойственная данной системе - rc.local и тут просто строками запуска, на то и _нестандартная_

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую воспользоваться Wireshark. Он умеет мониторить dbus и все вызовы можно сохранить и просматривать с отметками времени и фильтром.